# Does it ever make sense to sort by {$natural: 1}

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Are the two MongoDB statements below equivalent?

1. `db.collection.find(query).sort({$natural: 1})`
2. `db.collection.find(query).sort({})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order is quite clear about is:

> The order in which the database refers to documents on disk. This is the **default** sort order. See $natural

It makes sense the same way as any default value does - if you don't want to rely on defaults you can specify it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a million I could not find that article in the documentation. Makes a huge different as adding $natural prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Not always. If you search by _id, it will still use the index.